# For loop and ifelse-statement to change values in columns of data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, if-statement

I am trying to fill in values from another column into the columns of a data frame if the values of another data frame's column fulfill a certain condition. I use a for loop to iterate through the data frame and an ifelse-statement to stipulate the condition. When I run the code, it unfortunately does not produce the results I would like to have. It fills in the respective values according to the condition into BOTH columns I mention in the if-statement (time_trial_start; time_trial_end). What I would like to have is that only one column per row of the data frame mess_new_03 is filled according to the ifelse-statement.

This is the code I am using:

```
    for (i in row_index) {
      ifelse(row_index%%2 != 0, 
         mess_new_03$time_trial_start <- mess_new_03$time, 
         mess_new_03$time_trial_end <- mess_new_03$time) 
    }
```

I would be happy for any recommendations about how I can fix this. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Each run of your loop is replacing the entirety of a `column` with a copy of the `time` column - not a single value.  See my answer for a tidy approach, but there are other ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### A tidyverse approach:

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)

mess_new_03 <- mess_new_03 %>%
  mutate(time_trial_start = case_when(row_number() %% 2 != 0 ~ time),
         time_trial_end = case_when(row_number() %% 2 == 0 ~ time))
```

testing:

```
mess_new_03 <- data.frame(time = 1:50)
```

gives

```
> mess_new_03
   time time_trial_start time_trial_end
1     1                1             NA
2     2               NA              2
3     3                3             NA
4     4               NA              4
5     5                5             NA
6     6               NA              6
7     7                7             NA
8     8               NA              8
9     9                9             NA
10   10               NA             10
etc
```

### A Base R approach:

```
mess_new_03 <- data.frame(time = 1:50)
mess_new_03$time_trial_start <- NA
mess_new_03$time_trial_end <- NA

for (i in 1:nrow(mess_new_03)) {
  ifelse(i %% 2 != 0, 
         mess_new_03$time_trial_start[i] <- mess_new_03$time[i], 
         mess_new_03$time_trial_end[i] <- mess_new_03$time[i])
  }
```

### Base R without loops:

```
mess_new_03 <- data.frame(time = 1:50)
mess_new_03$time_trial_start <- NA
mess_new_03$time_trial_end <- NA

mess_new_03$time_trial_start[mess_new_03$time %% 2 != 0]<- mess_new_03$time[mess_new_03$time %% 2 != 0]
mess_new_03$time_trial_end[mess_new_03$time %% 2 == 0]<- mess_new_03$time[mess_new_03$time %% 2 == 0]
```

### Additional, needlessly convoluted tidy approach:

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
library(tidyr)

tidy2 <- mess_new_03
tidy2$id <- tidy2$time
tidy2$startend <- rep(c("start", "end"), times = 25) # my dataset has 50 rows
tidy2 <- tidy2 %>% pivot_wider(names_from = startend,
                      values_from = id,
                      names_glue = "time_trial_{startend}",
                      values_fill = NA)
```